# How to keep trying till successful in rxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to keep trying to establish TCP connection and when successful do something with that connection.

Assume this is my interface:

```
public interface ConnectionFactory {

    rx.Observable<Socket> createConnection(String host, int port);

}
```

I want to use it this way:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactoryImpl();

rx.Observable<Socket> rxSocket = factory.createConnection("abc.mycomp.com", 9999);

rxSocket.subscribe(...);
```

My question is - how will the implementation of ConnectionFactory.create(String, int) look like? Not looking for a working code but pointers would help. Is there a polling mechanism with retry available in rxJava 1.x?

It must keep on trying connecting (say) every 10 secs until successful and then call the subscriber.onNext(Socket). May suppress IOException/ any other connection exceptions.

Comment: IMO, `ConnectionFactory` should not have any retry logic.  The client which is using the factory should have the retry.  For example, the client could use a loop which uses the factory.  If the factory throws an exception because a connection could not be established then catch the exception, sleep, and `continue` to the next iteration.  But how many times should the code loop?  Why would a connection not be established during the first attempt?

Comment: Yeah, we can give a different name to it. There might be many reasons why connection might not be established which is not in our control e.g. the service we are trying to connect might be down at that point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ConnectionFactory as follows :

```
class ConnectionFactoryImpl implements ConnectionFactory {

    @Override
    public rx.Observable<Socket> createConnection(String host, int port) {
        Single<Socket> single = Single.create(sub -> {
            try {
             Socket socket = null;
             //create your socket
             sub.onSuccess(socket); 
         } catch (Exception e) {
             sub.onError(e);
         }
         });
         return single.toObservable();
    }
}
```

To retry the connection every 10 seconds, you can do something like this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactoryImpl();

rx.Observable<Socket> rxSocket = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(tick -> factory.createConnection("abc.mycomp.com", 9999)
                    .map(socket -> Optional.of(socket))
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> Optional.empty())
                    .filter(op -> op.isPresent())
                    .map(op -> op.get())
            )
    .take(1);

rxSocket
    .subscribe(socket -> {

    });
```

Be aware that `Observable.interval()` operates on `Schedulers.computation()` by default, which means the `rxSocket` executes asynchronously.